# Python Long UTC DateTime String

Tags: python, datetime

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
now.strftime('%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + now.strftime(' %p')
```

Is there a cleaner solution for this? I don't want the extra `000` to appear everytime in `%f`.

EDIT: Got some more possible combinations:

```
now.strftime('%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + (' PM' if now.hour > 11 else ' AM')
now.strftime('%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S.X %p').replace('X', str(now.microsecond / 1000))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, this is marginally cleaner, based on [@Gareth](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees)'s comment:

```
'{0:%d} {0:%b} {0:%Y} {0:%I}:{0:%M}:{0:%S}.{1:03d} {0:%p}'.format(now, now.microsecond // 1000)
```

The not so great part is treating `now.microseconds` differently from the rest. But since the vale is an integer in the range 0..999999, and you want the value divided by 1000, I don't see a way around. For example if the value is 12345, you would want to get `012`. Padding with zeros is easy, once the number is divided by 1000. Or you could pad with zeros up to 6 digits and take the first 3 characters, but I couldn't find a formatting exceptions to do that.

The advantage of this way over the original is instead of 2 calls to `strftime` and a string concatenation and a string slicing, there's now a single `.format` call.

Comment: The heck, that actually works? I love it! I didn’t know that you could use ``strftime``-formatters inside ``.format``.

Comment: To pad with zeros when millisecond < 100000. If you don't need fixed length always then you can simplify

Comment: I updated my post. `//` was unnecessary, `/` is enough, because `now.microsecond` and `1000` are both integers, so the division will give an integer

Comment: @janos Only in python2 and without ``from __future__ import division``. Don’t rely on it for the sake of upward compatibility.

Comment: Dammit. I knew I had a good reason for `//` in the first place. Thanks @JonasWielicki, I put it back. So in Python 3 division between integers results in `float`. Using `//` works as expected in both Python 2 and 3.